# What are synonyms of 'circus' that I can use in this context?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

> When I came back from work, I noticed that there were tons of people gathered around in the corridor. There was so much noise and hustle and bustle, it felt like a *circus*.

Is *circus* an appropriate word in this context, and can anyone suggest any synonyms that would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

***It was a zoo!***

***It was like feeding time in the monkey house!***

Answer (score 3):

Or it seems there is a ***carnival*** in the corridor!

Answer (score 1):

It is like a party.I think it can be like a private party

Comment: No it is not, party is completely from what I described in the  post.

Answer (score 1):

> There was so much noise and hustle and bustle, it felt like

- **main street** (or substitute the busiest well known local street) **at rush hour/peak hour**.

  This uses your syntax, and works well in your context as the referenced corridor shares elements with streets - they're both long, narrow and hard to get out of when they're over capacity.

If you don't absolutely need it to be a simile (i.e., if you can live without *felt like*), some other alternatives are below.

> There was so much noise and hustle and bustle, it was:

- chaos
- bedlam
- a madhouse
- a frenzy

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following words,

booby hatch, crazy house, cuckoo's nest, funny farm, funny house, loony bin, madhouse, nut house, nuthouse, sanatorium, snake pit.
For more word visit [this page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bedlam)